# Is it possible to set up ADSI linked server in SQL Server Express?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, active-directory

Is there any limitation in SQL Server Express that prevents you from creating a linked server to Active Directory?

(I don't have an AD environment available to test.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linked Servers do not seem to be an edition specific feature according to this MSDN article : **Linked Servers (Database Engine)** [SQL 2016](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx)

To add a linked server without the SQL Server Management Studio you would use the system stored procedures **sp_addlinkedserver** ([SQL 2008+](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx) or [SQL 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479(v=sql.110).aspx)) and **sp_addlinkedsrvlogin** ([SQL 2008+](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189811.aspx)).

A similar Q&A was previously posted in SO as [Linked Server In SQL Server Express](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4162171/1820861)